# Best practice for type checking props in Typescript with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typechecking, react-typescript

Below I have two variations of type checking props in React when used with Typescript.

> Variation 1

```
interface Props {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
}

const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }: Props) => {
  return (
    <></>
  );
};
```

> Variation 2

```
interface Props {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { prop1, prop2 } = props;
  return (
    <></>
  );
};
```

Which of the above variations is considered best practice and why?

Comment: For function components, use `FC<P>`. It gives you the other props you didn't think about (such as `children`) for free.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from typing the `props` of function component, you can type with `React.FC`/`React.FunctionComponent` (they are the same, just shorthand) as your second example.

Some differences are:

- `React.FC` is explicit about the return type, while the normal function version is implicit (or else needs additional annotation).

```
// Implicit return type
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }: Props) => {
  return (
    <></>
  );
};
```

- It provides type checking and auto-complete for static properties like `displayName`, `propTypes`, and `defaultProps`.

```
// Typing MyComponent.
// Will autocomplete `displayName`, `propTypes`, `defaultProps` etc
```

- It provides an implicit definition of `children`

```
// Implicit definition of children property
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, prop1, prop2 }) => {
  return (
    <></>
  );
};
```

> Which of the above variations is considered best practice and why?

Usually `React.FC` is used for typing a function component, the common sense is to differ it from a "function which returns React element", which resembles the first variant.

```
// Some helper function which returns React element
// But not a component like the first variant
const helperFunction = (args:Args) => {...}
// ^ typing with React.FC will give it a meaning of function component
```